# Laplace’s Equation in Hyperspherical Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry

I've been reading [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.3679v3.pdf) reference. I agree with everything they say but there's something that I can't really understand...They get that, for example n=2, the potential created by some source on a sphere is zero at $\theta=\pi/2$ and when $\theta\to\pi$ the potential goes to $+\infty$...

One would expect that the potential would decrease along $\theta$ and get a minimum value at $\theta=\pi$ so the force is zero at that point, since there would exist two geodesics that connect the point where the source is and it's antipodal point...why is this not the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A harmonic function cannot have a local minimum unless it is constant. One way to see this is variational: Suppose $u(x_0)=m$ is a strict local minimum and consider $\tilde u = \max(u,m+\epsilon)$ in a neighborhood of $x_0$ (and $\tilde u=u$ elsewhere). The function $\tilde u$ is a local perturbation of $u$ and has strictly smaller Dirichlet energy (since it is constant on part of the domain and agrees with $u$ otherwise). This contradicts the minimizing property of harmonic functions.

Another way to see this without calculation is to recall that the Laplacian is the divergence of the gradient. If $u$ has a strict local minimum at $x_0$, then in some spherical neighborhood of $x_0$ the gradient points away from $x_0$. Thus, its flux across the boundary of this neighborhood is nonzero, contradicting the divergence theorem.

Yet another interpretation: the fundamental solution comes from a point source. The gradient field has no sinks or sources apart from the singularities. A sphere is a compact manifold: nowhere to escape. So there must be a sink somewhere. For the symmetric solution they consider, the sink will be at the antipodal point of the source. E.g., the function is $-\infty$ at one pole, $+\infty$ at the other, and zero along the equator.

And yet another justification for the above is the reflection principle: if the harmonic function is zero on the equator of a sphere, then it is *odd* in the sense that $u(Rx)=-u(x)$ where $R$  is the reflection about the equator. So the singularity is reflected too.

Things are different on noncompact manifolds such as $\mathbb R^n$, because the gradient flow can try to escape to infinity. It escapes without trouble when $n\ge 3$. But when $n=2$, the exit to infinity is so narrow that a stampede results: the fundamental solution (logarithm) blows up at infinity.

Comment: Thank You for the answer. It took me a while to understand the implications and intrincacies of what you wrote but now it's understood. Thank you once again